# How to resolve a css url(image) in a webpack scss?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, webpacker

I am using webpacker if that is relevant
Folder structure is

```
app/javascripts
.
├── features
│   ├── bar.png
│   └── foo.css
├── index.scss
├── packs
│   └── application.js
```

In the application.js I have

```
import("index.scss");
```

Then in the index.scss I have

```
@import "features/foo.css";
```

and features/foo.css is

```
.foo {
  background-image: url(bar.png);
}
```

I can not change the code of foo.css. It comes like this from a vendor.

When I try to load it bar.png is not found

```
index.scss:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './bar.png'
    at webpackMissingModule (index.scss:4)
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./app/javascript/index.scss (index.scss:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:63)
    at Object../app/javascript/index.scss (index.scss?32bc:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:63)
    at __webpack_require__.t (bootstrap:161)
```

How could I load the bar.png?

Comment: This might help you: https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-images

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot change the code of foo.css. It comes like this from a vendor" when you are loading it in your app directory? Do you mean you don't want to change it? Because it looks like you can if you want to.

Comment: Yes. It means I don't want to change it, as it is a vendor library. I think I found a way. Will try to post a solution later